# How to resize the custom annotation pin image in MKMapView?

Tags: swift, mapkit

I am using swift 4. I have added MKMapView with some pins but I need to resize the pin image based on the map zooming.

So if anyone knows, how to resize the image based on map zooming?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Pins always say a constant size as the user zooms the map.

You'll want to look into using a `MKOverlay` and possibly a custom `MKOverlayRenderer` subclass. That will allow you to draw content that grows and shrinks as the user zooms in and out.