# How to change the custom pin image while zooming in MKMapView?

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have used `swift 4`. I am using `MKMapkit` and I have added custom annotation image for map pins. The problem is,

Let assume, I have 2 images like `image1` and `image2`. Initially, image1 is loaded for all map pins. Now, if I am going to zoom in to the map view means I need to replace the `image1` to `image2`. Again if I going to zoom out means I need to replace the `image2` to `image` 1.

So, if anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize the custom annotation pin image in MKMapView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782144/how-to-resize-the-custom-annotation-pin-image-in-mkmapview)

Comment: I've added my solution, let me know if it is helped. Feel free to ask anything else

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issue and I solve this like that

Firstly implement regionDidChangeAnimated in your map delegate

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {

    calculateZoomFactor()//Create global var named zoomFactor
    print("*************************")
    if zoomFactor > x { //Change the x value as you wish
        print("Zoom close, you can remove your annotations, and create with new image2")
    } else {
        print("Zoom out, remove annotations, and add new annotations with image 1")
    }
    print("*************************")
}
```

And this is my custom zoomFactor calculator

```
    func calculateZoomFactor() {
    let zoomWidth = mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width
    let zoomFactor = (log2(zoomWidth)) - 8.785//You can change this constant also
    self.zoomFactor = zoomFactor
}
```